# git submodule svn external

Tags: php, svn, git

Let's say I have 3 git repositories, each with a `lib` and `tests` folder in the root. All 3 repositories are part of what I want to be a single package, however it is important to me to keep the repositories separate.

I am new to git coming from svn, so I have been reading up on `submodules` and how they differ from `svn:externals`. In SVN I could have a single

```
lib/vendor/package
```

directory, and inside `package` I could setup 3 externals pointing to each of my 3 repositories `lib` directory, renaming it appropriately like

```
lib/vendor/package/a  -> repo1/lib
lib/vendor/package/b  -> repo2/lib
lib/vendor/package/c  -> repo3/lib
```

but from my understanding this is not possible with git. Am I missing something?

Really I'm hoping this can be solved in one of two ways.

1. Someone will point out how to create a 4th git repository which has the other 3 as submodules organized as I have mentioned above (where I can have an `a`, `b`, and `c` folder inside the root)
2. Someone will point out how to set this up using `svn:externals` in combination with githubs svn support, referencing the `lib` directory within each git repository (from my understanding this is impossible)

#### Update:

I had actually tried to follow the submodules tutorial you linked to, but I run into the following problem.

Doing things as shown above, instead of a mapping like

```
lib/vendor/package/a  -> repo1/lib
lib/vendor/package/b  -> repo2/lib
lib/vendor/package/c  -> repo3/lib
```

I am left with

```
lib/vendor/package/a  -> repo1
lib/vendor/package/b  -> repo2
lib/vendor/package/c  -> repo3
```

this is not ideal since now to access `ClassA` inside `repo1`'s `lib` folder, the path is

```
lib/vendor/package/a/lib/ClassA
```

when I'm really trying to get (and this is possible with svn:externals)

```
lib/vendor/package/a/ClassA
```

since `a` above is actually `repo1/lib`, and not the root directory of `repo1`.

Something like this is important since, with `PHP5.3` for example, using the `SplClassLoader` ( http://gist.github.com/221634 ), it requires a namespace-to-directory mapping like

```
\Package\a\ClassA  -> lib/vendor/package/a/ClassA
```

this is where my conceptual misunderstanding is, how to setup that 4th git repository to allow my directory mappings like above.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, Git submodules can not directly do exactly what you want. It works in SVN because the root of a repository, branches, and any subdirectory thereof are the same kind of object. In Git, a repository, a branch, and a directory are all distinct kinds of objects (you can not use a directory as a full repository or as a branch).

There are a couple of indirect ways to accomplish what you want though.

### Using Submodules and Symlinks

The core of a Git submodule is a clone of another repository in the work tree of the “superproject”<sup>*</sup>.
Git only clones full repositories. It is not possible to clone just a single subdirectory out of an existing repository<sup>†</sup>.

<sup>*</sup> Normal submodules also require a special reference in the superproject's commits/index and (normally) an entry in the superproject's `.gitmodules` file.
It is possible to have non-tracked clones of other repositories in an unrelated working tree, but such usage does not create a submodule.
<sup>†</sup> Git 1.7.0 and later has a “sparse checkout” feature, but it would not help to relocate the `lib` directory the top level of each submodule clone.

You might, however be able to use Git's support for symbolic links to do something that is fairly close:

```
#
# Make the lib directory of each submodule appear in the superproject as
# lib/vendor/packages/$submod_name
#
# With this structure in each of the submodules (a, b, c):
#
#    lib/
#    tests/
#
# We end up with this structure in the superproject:
#
#    lib/
#        vendor/
#            packages/
#                a     (a symlink to ../../../_submodules/a/lib)
#                b     (a symlink to ../../../_submodules/b/lib)
#                c     (a symlink to ../../../_submodules/c/lib)
#    _submodules
#        a/            (a Git submodule)
#            lib/
#            tests/
#        b/            (a Git submodule)
#            lib/
#            tests/
#        c/            (a Git submodule)
#            lib/
#            tests/
#
add_one() {
    dir=lib/vendor/package
    dest="$dir/$1"
    # use fewer ".."s to put the _submodules closer to the symlinks
    s=../../../_submodules/"$1"
    git submodule add "$2" "$dir/$s"
    ln -s "$s"/lib "$dest"
    git add "$dest"
}

cd "$main_repo_toplevel"
mkdir -p lib/vendor/package
add_one a git@githost.example.com:user/package-a.git
add_one b git://public.example.com/work/package-b-dev.git
add_one c ssh://special.example.com/foo.git
```

### Using *git subtree*

apenwarr's [*git subtree*](http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) can split off and merge parts of repositories (i.e. individual subdirectories; it is a wrapper around [“subtree merging”](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) with other nice features). The first step would be to extract the history of `lib` in each of your sub-projects. Then, either directly use the extracted history as a submodule, or use *git subtree* to do a subtree merge into your main repository. Either way, this would introduce an extra step (re-extracting the `lib` history) before you could integrate changes from a sub-project into your main repository.

Comment: If the symlinks point to subdirectories of the vendor packages, the checkouts in _submodules can be sparse checkouts, no?

Comment: @Jeremy: That seems like it would be okay. You might have to mange the sparseness manually though (i.e. it does not look like *git submodule* can automatically configure sparseness when doing `init` and/or `update`, e.g. in a new clone of the superproject).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a forth 'lib' main Git repo, with:

- `lib/vendor/package` content
- 3 **submodules** (see "[true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)")

But this reference is totally independent from any 'svn:external' property you may have setup in a mirror SVN repo.

So if you have 3 SVN repos already, you can `git-svn` them, publish them on GitHub, and then create a fourth repo on GitHub in which you will add those 3 Git repos as submodules, following the [submodules tutorial](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial) (supposing here you have all 4 repos already on GitHub)

```
$ mkdir -p lib/vendor/package
$ cd lib/vendor/package
$ for package in a b c d; do
$ git submodule add git://github.com/path/to/$package.git $package
$ done
$ cd ..
$ git commit -m "lib with submodules"
$ git push
```