# Commit changes to minify's config.php when set up as a git submodule

Tags: git, config, minify, git-submodules

In my web app project I have Google [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) set up as a git submodule; the idea is that I can keep the minify library up to date by simply running `git submodule update`.
My problem is I have made local changes to the minify `config.php` file which I want to publish as part of my app... but how can I commit this change to the super-project?

Other sources (e.g. [How do I “commit” changes in a git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542910/how-do-i-commit-changes-in-a-git-submodule)) say I need to commit and push the submodule first, but obviously I'm not going to push the changes in my config file to the *public* minify repository.

What's the best way of handling this sort of set up... I imagine it should be quite common but cannot find any solid recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to "fork" the Google minify project, that way you'll get your own copy. You'll be able to push fixes on it and to update it from an `upstream` remote (this is the common name). Finally, your submodule will point to your copy.

About the `upstream` remote, it should point to the Google minify repository, and the `origin` remote will point to your copy. This is a kind of convention. You always pull new commits from the upstream, and you'll push new commits + your fixes to the origin.

This is a clean way to manage this sort of set up.