# Keeping WordPress in version control - separate repo for theme

Tags: wordpress, git

I have my WordPress project under Git and have WordPress as a submodule. I want to keep my theme development in a separate submodule, but within the current setup and am having some difficulties getting the theme setup as a submodule.

Here is my file system:

```
/.git (master repo)
/index.php
/wp-config.php
/wordpress (WordPress repo as a submodule)
/wp-content 
  themes
     test-theme (theme repo)
        .git
        index.php
        (etc...)
```

Now when I push my master repo to github, and try and clone it on another machine, the wordpress submodule downloads fine, but my theme folder does not, and I get an error about submodule not being defined.

I've tried using this to add my theme as a sub-module:

```
git submodule add ./wp-content/themes/test-theme/.git ./wp-content/themes/test-theme
```

but I get the following error: "remote (origin) does not have a url defined in .git/config"

How do I defined my theme repo as a submodule, when it is essentially hosted "inside" the project and not at a separate repository online?

Thanks.

Comment: I just put wp-content as root of my git and then use .gitignore to remove plugins that I don't want to see. Custom plugins and theme is tracked together.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052006/moving-the-git-repository-to-a-child-folder

Answer (score 5):

I'm still relatively new to using submodules but I have been trying to do something similar and found two blog posts quite helpful: one by [Clint Berry](http://clintberry.com/2011/speed-up-your-wordpress-development-cycle-with-git/) and another by [David Winter](http://davidwinter.me/install-and-manage-wordpress-with-git/).

The principle of a submodule is that it should have a separate repo and then when you add that submodule to a new project the add submodule command should be pointing to the repo:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/youruseraccount/test-theme.git ./wp-content/themes/test-theme
git init
git update
```

I believe this is why you are getting the error, there is no URL associated with the origin.  Look in the files .gitmodule and .git/config to confirm.  If I am correct, the git init will add the necessary entries in .git/config and git update this will pull the theme from the repo and put it into the subdirectory.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542910/how-do-i-commit-changes-in-a-git-submodule) for how to commit changes to the submodule and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule) for how to remove the submodule.

Comment: The second link (David Winter) is broken.

Comment: Updated the link.