# Unable to add changes to my repository

Tags: git

I've modified a puppet module I previously cloned from it's own repository on github. The only thing I changed is a configuration file template, no big deal (pg_hba.conf.erb for the pgsql-aware).

The problem is that I'm not able to add the modified module to my repository.

```
[ngw@chienandalusia:~/outline.li]$ git status                     (08-13 15:18)
# On branch develop
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   puppet/modules/postgresql (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
[ngw@chienandalusia:~/outline.li]$ git add puppet                 (08-13 15:19)
[ngw@chienandalusia:~/outline.li]$ git add puppet/modules/postgresql
[ngw@chienandalusia:~/outline.li]$ git status                     (08-13 15:20)
# On branch develop
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   puppet/modules/postgresql (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I currently don't see any reason for this behaviour and not being a git expert I'm not entirely sure how to debug this. FWIW there's nothing in my .gitignore that prevents the changes to be staged for commit, and git status apparently agrees with me. Even using the -f flag didn't help.

Does someone have any clue?

Comment: Does puppet/modules/postgresql/.git exist? Maybe Git submodules are in action.

Comment: mmm, yes I do have puppet/modules/postgresql/.git

Comment: Do you have any rule for this folder in your .gitignore file ?

Comment: @ngw: Why is there a `.git` folder in `puppet/modules/postgresql`?? There should only be one in the root (i.e. in the same folder where you have `puppet`).

Comment: @aaron-digulla because I've cloned the module in my own directory.

Comment: @tommyk nothing in .gitignore that could preclude the inclusion of that directory.

Comment: Does `git add -n puppet/modules/postgresql` say something useful?

Answer (score 2):

`puppet/modules/postgresql` is a git submodule, changes to it do not affect git project. To make changes to a submodule you should cd to submodule directory and add/commit work, pull, push, go back to root and commit/push again.

Keep in mind that pushing submodule will push to a different remote then the root project.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542964/2578489.